# EditText view's text after maximum length

Tags: android

I have an EditText for an email field. My mobile screen is really small and my email is longer than the field.

I want that the text advance, I mean, I want to stop reading the beginning of my email and continue reading what I'm reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

update ur Xml :

```
 android:singleLine="true"
 android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
```

Answer (score 0):

Review the InpuType options:

there you'll find  this :

```
android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
```

along with other options that will help you,